# How to determine if a GUID is odd or even in SWIFT?

Tags: swift, guid

I have a list of i.e. users, which all have an identifier that is a GUID.
I want to separate the users in two pools randomly for performing an A/B test.
If I can do an odd/even on the identifier, it will enable me to do that.

How do I do a odd/even check on a GUID in a String property, in SWIFT?

Is the modulus two done on the hash and how do I do that?

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: "I want to separate the users in two pools randomly for performing an A/B test" What about not use that UUID, and just randomly put into a different group?

Comment: @Larme And how would you separate into two groups approx. evenly without a seed? I have an unlimited number of "batches"/pages of users, so I never will have all at once.
I could do odd/even on the position in the array, though.

Comment: %2 on the index indeed, that’s what I was thinking of, or a seed, but I wasn’t sure about your exact needs

Comment: @DávidPásztor I actually haven't tried something, because I'm in doubt how to. I know how to use modulus to do odd/even and I know how to use UUIDs. But modulus operates on numbers and UUIDs is a string, so what I'm asking is how to use them together.
If I just wanted to know how to do either, there are plenty of answers already.

Comment: @Larme Thanks. I could have been more explicit about the batches/paging. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod 2 applies on numbers only so yes, by taking hash of `UUID`/`GUID` and then applying the mod function should be enough:

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
let hashValue = uuid.hash

if hashValue.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 2).remainder == 0 {
    print("even")
} else {
    print("odd")
}
```

`.hash` is available on `String` bt default so you can use it directly

---

PS:
`hashValue.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 2).remainder`
or
`hashValue % 2`

Whatever floats your boat

Comment: Interesting idea to use the hash value. Though why would someone write `quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 2).remainder` instead of just `% 2` is beyond me :)

Comment: @mojuba Yup. Well... `% 2` gives only remainder whereas `quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy:)` gives both quotient & remainder, so more flexible in use [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger/3017639-quotientandremainder)

Comment: Yes, and the long form works for floating point too. Interestingly `%` worked for FP in Swift but it was then removed in favor of this function. But anyway, shorter form, if it's available, is always and unconditionally better than a longer form. It's less to read.

Comment: @mojuba aah, yes, that too, `%` is unsupported for floating numbers.